# Next.js 13 (app directory) - Access page metadata in Layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using the new `app` folder structure with Next.js 13 project, and I would like to display a subheader in the `RootLayout` containing the value of the Page title (I'm using metadata on each page to configure the head title).

Is there any way to directly access that value with SSR?

Example  layout.js:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children) {
    const pageTitle = "???"; // How to get this value?
    return (
      <html>
        <body>
          <HeaderComponent />
          <div className="subheader">
            <h3>{pageTitle}</h3>        <------ HERE
          </div>
          <div className="content">{children}</div>
          <FooterComponent />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
);
```

Example page.js:

```
export const metadata = {
    title: "Login"
};

export default function Login() {
    return (
        <div>Login form</div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot get that `metadata` in the layout with SSR, at least so far. A [layout](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/layout) in the `app` folder gets passed an object that contains `children` and `params` when a dynamic route is used. That's it.

Its role is to wrap all components of a route segment, not only `page.js`, but also `loading.js`, `not-found.js`...

Anything specific to a component should be in it directly. A page title should be in `page.js` itself. Next.js decided that a project should be structured so.

Comment: That's a fair explanation and i have to agree on all the points. I'll restructure the project to move the reponsibility for the subheader to the Page level.  Thanks a lot, i accept this as a correct answer.