How show data from Metadata in UI?
Use Next Js 14 app router.
I want show title from Metadata as  on page.
Do something like this:
// app/layout.tsx

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const title = metadata.title as string;
  return (

    <html lang="ru">
      <body className={font.className}>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Its work fine, but when i go to site.com/blog
// app/blog/page.tsx

import { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Blog", // new title
};

const BlogPage = async () => {
  

  return (
    <>
    blog
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogPage;


I expect the title in the layout to change to "Blog" too, but it doesn't.
Is there any mechanism to synchronize metadata and  titles?

Unlikely this would work even if there was an api available for it.

This is also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75443992/next-js-13-app-directory-access-page-metadata-in-layout

This actually would be an interesting, retrieving page metadatas in layout.tsx.
Or a complete disaster that will confuse developers.
